# How to connect with bot from another app?

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

I have created a core bot with basic workflow to collect information from end-users, which is hosted on `http://localhost:3978`, and exposes an endpoint to send message `http://localhost:3978/api/messages` (POST)

I can start and chat with bot via `Bot Framework Emulator`, but I dont know how to interact with it via `CodeBehind`, or from another web application. I read some information about `Direct Line API` but I am still quite confused.

Could I implement my own `Direct Line API` to connect with my bot?
Is there any samples to interact with bot from another application?
Is there direct ways to connect with bot?

Please sorry if any typo misstakes.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* connect to the bot using the [Directline REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), but it would be much easier to implement [WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) into your app. There are [TONS of samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#samples-list) to help you get started.

Emulator is just an [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) app that uses WebChat.

Quick Start:

1. Clone the [Getting Started Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.a.getting-started-full-bundle)
2. Get your WebChat Secret from `Azure Portal > Resource Group > Web App Bot > Channels`

[image]

3. Edit this part of the `index.html`:

```js
const res = await fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
const { token } = await res.json();
```

To just:

```js
const token = '<yourWebChatSecret>`
```

...replacing `<yourWebChatSecret>` with the one you copied from Step 2.

4. `cd` into the folder containing `index.html` and run `npx serve`
5. Open the site at `localhost:5000`

Comment: Hi @mdrichardson, Your solution seems good. Where do I get the token from. I am using Microsoft Bot Emulator and bot is never connected to Azure yet. Thanks. The main issue is I would like to chat to the bot without the bot emulator. I have searched examples but none so far.